# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'type' was corrupted

Tags: c

I'm studying for an exam and this is on my practice test.  Why can't I change the type of vehicle after the number 1?  Then I also get  Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'type' was corrupted when I change the code. and also want to create 15 lots of parking.

```
float rate(char, int, int);

int main()
{
    int a, b, v, x;
    float r;
    char type;
    printf("\t**\n");
    printf("\t! Welcome to Perdana Parking Management System !\n");
    printf("\t__\n");
```

This line didn't loop after number 1

```
printf("\n\tEnter the type of your vehicle (C for car, V for Van) : ");
        scanf("%c", &type);

 
    for (x = 0; x < 15; x++)
    {
        if (type == 'c' || type == 'C' || type == 'v' || type == 'v')
        {
            printf("\n\tEnter vehicle number : ");
            scanf("%d", &v);
            printf("\n");
            printf("\tEnter the Hours Vehicle entered the lot ( from 0 to 24): ");
            scanf("%d", &a);
            printf("\t\n");

            printf("\tEnter the Hours vehicle left the parking lot ( from 0 to 24): ");
            scanf("%d", &b);
            printf("\t\n");

            r = rate(type, a, b);
            printf("\tYour Parking Fee is RM %.2f \n", r);
        }

        else
        {
            printf("\tYou have to Enter the type of your vehicle correctly\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

float rate(char t, int x, int y)
{
    float rate = 0;
    switch (t)
    {
    case 'C':
    case 'c':if (y - x <= 1)
    {
        rate = 4;
        break;
    }
            else if (y - x > 1 && y - x <= 3)
    {
        rate = ((((y - x) - 1) * 2) + 4);
        break;
    }
            else if (y - x > 3 && y - x <= 24)
    {
        rate = (2 * 2) + (4 * 1) + (((y - x) - 3) * 1);
        break;
    }

    case 'V':
    case'v':if (y - x <= 1)
    {
        rate = 6;
        break;
    }
           else if (y - x > 1 && y - x <= 3)
    {
        rate = ((((y - x) - 1) * 3) + 6);
        break;
    }
           else if (y - x > 3 && y - x <= 24)
    {
        rate = (3 * 2) + (6 * 1) + (((y - x) - 3) * 2);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
    return rate;
}
```

Comment: you can't change it after number 1 because that's what the program says. If you want to be able to change it after number 1, then you should write that in the program.

Comment: how to write it in the program can u show the example

Comment: Do you know what a loop does?